# MySQL check blank or null values

Tags: mysql, sql, null, case

I need help verifying the empty or null values in mysql
I tried to use this way in my case but is not working:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
          WHEN account_type      IS NULL THEN 'Uninformed'
          WHEN account_type = ''         THEN 'Empty '
    END as Type,
COUNT(accounts.id)                     AS Total
FROM
accounts
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: please post the results you get and what is desired

Comment: Please wait will implement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct. At last you need to add `group by account_type;`.

Query should be like this.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN account_type IS NULL THEN 'Uninformed'
        WHEN account_type = '' THEN 'Empty '
END AS Type,
COUNT(accounts.id) AS Total
FROM    accounts
GROUP BY account_type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN account_type IS NULL THEN 'Uninformed'
     WHEN account_type = ''  THEN 'Empty '
END as Type,
COUNT(accounts.id) AS Total
FROM accounts
group by account_type
```

You are missing a `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Another sleek way of writing the same query without the case statement would be something like......

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(account_type , 'Uninformed'),''),'Empty') AS Type
     ,COUNT(accounts.id)                     AS Total
FROM accounts
GROUP BY ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(account_type , 'Uninformed'),''),'Empty')
```